# 2.5D engine on Android?

Tags: android, 2d, 2.5d

Such a minus score of this question shows the power of stackoverflow and and wrong understanding of 2.5D, there are no 2.5D game in fact, Only 2D or 3D.

> I want to develop a 2.5D game on Android just like 'minigore2' on
>   iphone, Is there any 2.5D engine in Android?
>
> This is the effect I want:

[image]

Comment: This question is way too broad to be answerable.

Comment: Just make a 3D game with a camera angle of what you see here...There is really no such thing as a 2.5D game...

Comment: Minigore can't change the angle of camera so I think it is a fake 3D game.

Comment: This actually is a very confusing question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2.5D) states, you can either render 2D images on the screen giving the effect of a 3D world. For this I would suggest you have a look at the [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) class on the Android developer site as well as having a look at this Android Game Dev. [link](http://www.edu4java.com/androidgame.html)

If you prefer to rather create a 3D world and set the camera at a fixed angle and location the I suggest you have a read on OpenGl ES for Android.

If you are looking for Game Engines for Android, I suggest you have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407155/game-engines-for-android).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Luke, I found the unity3d in the thead you gave, That is a really wonderful engine.